# select date and time from 2 columns mysql with date_format

Tags: mysql

I have a table formatted as follows:

```
|   ID   |   Name  |     date       |   time     |
|   1    |    A    |   2020-05-04   |  19:00:00  | 
|   2    |    B    |   2020-05-04   |  19:10:00  | 
|   3    |    C    |   2020-05-04   |  19:20:00  |
```

I want to select the result between `2020-05-04 - 19:00:00` and `2020-05-04 - 19:20:00`, so I'm expecting the result to be `B`

And if I use date_format:

```
SELECT * 
  from table 
 where (date > DATE_FORMAT('2020-05-04 19:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %T')) 
   AND (date < DATE_FORMAT('2020-05-04 19:20:00','%Y-%m-%d %T'))
```

it ends up being wrong because it only uses the date.
How can I search in 2 columns at the same time?

Comment: What is the data type of the 2 columns?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: Hi, date is date type YYYY-MM-DD, time is time type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two columns using the [timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) function:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
 WHERE timestamp(`date`, `time`) > '2020-05-04 19:00:00'
 AND   timestamp(`date`, `time`) < '2020-05-04 19:20:00'
```

Comment: I confess I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ADDTIME(`date`, `time`) BEETWEEN '2020-05-04 19:00:00' AND '2020-05-04 19:20:00';
```

If you need strict non-equiation with one or both datetame range borders then replace BETWEEN..END with 2 according unequations.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * from table where (date > DATE_FORMAT('2020-05-04','%Y-%m-%d')) AND (date < DATE_FORMAT('2020-05-04','%Y-%m-%d')) AND (time > DATE_FORMAT('19:00:00',  '%T')) AND (time < DATE_FORMAT('19:20:00',  '%T'))